# Java unusual behaviour of variables

Tags: java, android

I have class like this (Actually onResponse method parses JSON, but I removed that piece od code for the sake of simplicity):

```
class DistRespListener implements HttpClient.HttpResponseListener {

private double dist;

@Override
public void onResponse(HttpMetaResponse response) {
    Double distTemp = 14.7;
    setDist(distTemp);
    Log.d("distanceInner2", String.valueOf(this.dist));
}

public void setDist(double dist) {
    this.dist = dist;
    Log.d("distanceInner4", String.valueOf(this.dist));
}
public double getDist() {
    Log.d("distanceInner3", String.valueOf(this.dist));
    return this.dist;
}
```

Later in the code, I make this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
DistRespListener distRespListener = new DistRespListener();
httpClient.executeRequestUsingOwnListener(new HttpGet(builder.build().toString()), distRespListener);

Log.d("distanceOuter", String.valueOf(distRespListener.getDist()));
```

Method executeRequestUsingOwnListener of httpClient object calls method onResponse() of distRespListener object.

Problem is, getDist() method always return "0.0".

Comment: Isn't that request done async?

Comment: You set dist before that, right?

Comment: @Simon yes, it is. onResponse() gets called inside onPostExecute()

Comment: @user3199693 does the Log 'distanceInner2' print '14.7' and the 'distanceOuter' '0.0'? If that is the case, it is because the 'distanceOuter' is logged right after the request has been sent, when a response has not been received yet.

Comment: As long as you logged some information, could we see the relevant log output?

Comment: distanceInner2 and distanceInner4 are 14.7. distanceInner3 and distanceOuter are 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Check the order in which the log messages appear - it will be distanceinner3, distanceouter, distanceinner2 and distanceinner4. That tells us that the first two values are logged before the response is received while the latter two are logged after. That is why you always see 0 for the first two.